# filter homepage questions by topic

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I like looking at the new questions posted in the past few minutes on the stackoverflow.com homepage.

Is there a way to filter this list by topic? I'm not much of an expert in anything but a few subject areas.

When I click "Unanswered" I get questions that are months old.

Comment: If you add favorite tags, the homepage will adjust to show you mostly questions that are from those tags.

Comment: this works for the most part. I'm still get a few unrelated questions on the homepage that don't have any of my favoriate tags.

Comment: That's intentional—10% of homepage questions are randomly picked, so that all questions get some exposure. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Comment: that explains it. I thought they were sponsored questions at first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get newest question of particular tag (topic) by using the following URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+or+sql
```

In the given example you will find only question tagged `mysql` or `sql` or both. You can add more tags in the URL like this `+or+tagname`.